# How can I populate a detail view from clicking a node in a Kendo list view?

Tags: listview, kendo-ui

I am building an app whereby the user clicks through a list view, until they reach an item that they wish to view details about.
I am having trouble working out how to do that final step and fill a detail view with the data associated with the 'node' the user has just clicked on.

Has anyone information or advice please?

Comment: It depends what kinda details view you want to show user. ListView has change event where you can get selected observable. One possibility is to create form it databind observable to it.

Comment: @Japi.  The problem I am having is that as soon as the user clicks (or touches) the last level in the listview, (where I want it to then show a page containing some of the sibling data for the selected listview item), all bound data seems to be lost.  I am getting close to the conclusion that it may not be possible to pass data between different types of view  with Kendo alone, and may have to include AngularJS into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out a solution for this.

Using a seemingly undocumented property, _data I was able to create an array of all of the items in the returned dataset.
I first captured a guid then set a loop going to compare the guid with those in my array.
Once a match was found, the loop was broken out of and I could then execute the template with the values in the array that I had stopped at.

My function is as follows:

```
function bindTaskView(e){
    var view = e.view;
    var itemData = e.view.params.parentID;
    var element = e.view.element;
    var dataSet = $("#hierarchical-listview").data("kendoMobileListView").dataSource._data;
    for(var i=0; i < dataSet.length; i++)
        {
            if(dataSet[i].Guid == itemData){
                console.log("dataSet item "+i+" Description   :  "+dataSet[i].Description);
                viewData = dataSet[i];
                break;
                }
        }

    var template = kendo.template($("#taskTimeTemplate").html());
    var htmlCode = template(viewData);
    $("#taskTime").html(htmlCode);

}
```

Comment: using kendo private variables (_***) is risky because they could change in future releases so stick to API methods. In your case it's dataSource.data() method in place of dataSource._data variable